# Cannot select input of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I want to select a specific input to the div but it does not select, if I select label it works fine. The code line with stars is where the issue below inside the code:

```
$('#billing_first_name, #billing_last_name, #billing_city').click(function() {

var label = $("label[for='"+this.id+"']");
//this line below does not work
**var input = $("input[for='"+this.id+"']");**

$(this).on('blur', function() {

    if (( $(this).val() === '' ) || ( !$(this).val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$' ) )) {
        input.css("border-color", "#ff0000");
        label.css("color", "#ff0000");
    } else{
        input.css("border-color", "#ccc");
        label.css("color", "#404040");
    }


})

$('.backToCheckout').click( function(){
    input.css("border-color", "#ccc");
    label.css("color", "#404040");
})

});
```

Looking forward to some tips and help thanks.

Comment: input's don't use `for` attributes, so unless you actually put one on your input element for some odd reason, than that selector won't work to find it

Comment: Never bind event handler inside event handler

Comment: please explain what do you want to achieve

Comment: Can you post your html structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to select by id, then try this

```
var input = $("input#" + this.id);
```

Comment: why not just `var input = $(this)`?